# SCRIPT5007 Unable To get value of the property 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I need help resolving this error in IE9: "SCRIPT5007 Unable To get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined"

```js
findParent = function (father, str, prop) {
    /**
     * Go up the DOM tree and find the parent element with the specified class or prop name.
     * @param {Object} father - (HTMLElement)
     * @param {String} str - the class of the father
     * @param {string} prop - some other property such as name or id
     * @example var parentEl = findParent(container, 'genericForm', 'name');
     */
    'use strict';

    if (prop === undefined || typeof prop !== 'string') {
        prop = 'className';
    }

    while ((father !== undefined || typeof father !== 'string' || father !== null) && (father = father.parentElement) && !(father[prop].indexOf(str) >= 0));

    return father;
};

var container = document.getElementById('description');
var parentEl = findParent(container, 'gForm', 'name');
alert(parentEl);
```

```html
<form action="/gform.html" class="campaign-forms" method="post" name="gForm">

    <fieldset class="fieldset" title="Type your question...">
        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Type your question..." data-ana-label="Type your question..."></textarea>
        <small class="error"><i class="close">×</i> This is a required field</small>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

I expect it to return the `<form>` in this instance. Please help.

Comment: Looking at the debugger in IE, it says that `father` is `fieldset` element and `prop` is `name`. However, the fieldset in your code doesn't have a name, hence an error.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it keep going up the DOM until it finds the parent with the specified prop? That's what `while` does, right? That's how it works elsewhere at least, Chrome, Firefox, Safari...

Comment: No, `father['name']` is `undefined`, it hasn't the said method.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about getting this functionality to work in IE, the same as it does in other browsers?

Comment: That's a bit complex condition. Maybe IE has different operator precedence here (it shouldn't though). Spreading a part of the code to the body of `while` might help. What are you trying to achieve? Just find the form, or create a generic function to find a parent with conditions given in the arguments?

Comment: I have this function used in several places and the html is not always the same. Sometimes the parent/child relationship goes several levels deep. This `findParent` function seemed to be the way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, that there's a difference between browsers. When `father[prop]` is not explicitly defined, IE returns `undefined`, other browsers seem to return an empty string.

To fix this you can detect `undefined` and replace it with an empty string, something like this:

```
findParent = function (father, str, prop) {
    'use strict';

    if (prop === undefined || typeof prop !== 'string') {
        prop = 'className';
    }

    while (father && (father = father.parentElement) && !((father[prop] || '').indexOf(str) >= 0));
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return father;
};
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2hzvw8a/1/).

(I've just simplified the condition a bit, you can use the original `father`-exists-detection if you want.)

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you again.